# Cannot get stackview to adjust correctly in scrollview

Tags: swift, autolayout, scrollview, uistackview

I have a content view embedded into a scrollview. On this content view, I have an ImageView and a stackview with several labels. Two of the labels should wrap when the lines are too long. When the bottom line wraps, I want it to activate the scrollview. Currently, I have constraints set like this:

```
Scrollview -> Parent view controller = 0,0,0,0
UIView -> Scrollview = 0,0,0,0
ImageView -> UIView = Top: 20, Bottom: 45, Leading/Trailing: 80
Stackview -> Imageview = Top: 45
Stackview -> UIView = Leading: 20, Bottom: 40, Trailing: 150
```

The labels are default and the frame hugs the text. (I'll post an image.)

The image below only shows one of the attempts of setting a constraint on the label to try to force word wrap - it didn't work.

[image: Constraints]

Here's what I'm getting:

[image: notWordWrapping]

After the bottom line wraps, the stackview should grown downward and enable scrolling. I need to be able to scroll, but other things that I've seen is that it will only scroll to touch the last line and bounces out of view. I haven't been able to figure out how to add enough padding to the line to keep it from doing that, but that's another issue I believe.

I've tried setting the width constraint on the stack view to force the label to wrap. The label settings are 0 lines, and line break is set to word wrap. I've also tried settings a smaller trailing constraint to the label to force it to wrap, but that's not working either.

This is all being done in Interface Builder, so no code. I can move to all code if it will fix my issue though. Just let me know what else I need to post to help solve this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1- You need to ctrl drag from the contentView of the scrollview to the main outer view of the vc and select Equal-widths

2- You need to set a height constraint for the imageView

3- Set distribution of the stackview to `fill`

Comment: It appears that changing fill corrected this issue. Thanks! Now the scrollview doesn't appear to be working...